# How do I relate a user to a channel entry from a form?

Tags: form, user-profile, current-user

I have a channel which has a relate to user field, how do I setup the front-end form which is a user details update form so they can select a channel entry from a drop down and when saved, have it relate that user to the channel entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving an entry field type as part of your plug-in it needs to be an array of IDs in order to work correctly. This can either be handled via a plug-in or in the form by passing the value as an array to that field handle.

Plug-in:

```php
$user->setContentFromPost(array(
    'entryField' => array(10)
));
$success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

Front-end form:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="fields[relatedEntry][]" value="{{entry.id}}">
```

Comment: Ah my bad, i dont think i have explained it well. The channel entries already exist, when a user updates their profile from a front end form i have created, they get to choose a channel entry from a drop down list. Problem i am having is that by selecting a channel entry and saving, the related field in their profile is remaining empty. Basically, what do i do to the form field in the user update form, for craft to relate the user to the chosen channel entry.

Comment: So you want them to be able to choose a specific entry to be related to their profile?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: My dropdown list of channel entries consists of the entry.id for the value, and entry.title for the label. and the field has a name of fields[myrelatedfield].

Comment: updated answer, working on a code example now!

Comment: ah, so you cant relate a user to a channel entry from the form? as in craft doesnt handle this out the box? If i understand you correctly. i am already doing this so admins can view the channel entry to see a list of users.

Comment: see updated answer, that should get you what you need