# Issue with storing an Entry

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to store an entry in a plugin. The entry has a field 'tags' that relates to another entry. I am trying to store it with the following code.

```
$newsItem = new EntryModel();
$newsItem->sectionId = craft()->sections->getSectionByHandle('news')->id;
$newsItem->getContent()->tags = $tag->id;
craft()->entries->saveEntry($newsItem);
```

When I `var_dump(craft()->entries->saveEntry($newsItem))` I get a `false` response.

Also, in this situation we cannot use the method `setContentFromPost()` so we need to do it from within the plugin and not from a front-end form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is more to your code or not but looks like you need to set the `title` as well as other required fields. In addition the entries field is expecting an array of `entryId`s.

Here is a link to the saveEntry method in the EntriesService, which shows the required fields:
https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#saveEntry-detail

This answer is somewhat similar in that they are relating an entry, but you can see that the `entryField` is being set with an `array`.

[How do I relate a user to a channel entry from a form?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/how-do-i-relate-a-user-to-a-channel-entry-from-a-form/14563#14563)

Comment: Yes, the issue was a required ```title```. And ```$newsItem->getErrors()``` showed this error to me. thanks @Brad

Answer (score 1):

Along the same train of thought as [mcclaskiem's](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14567/57) answer, you're likely getting a validation error.

If you check `$newsItem->getErrors()` after you call `craft()->entries->saveEntry($newsItem);`, you can see which attributes are failing validation and why.